# Radio list appears horizontally on IE when it should have been vertical

Tags: list, internet-explorer, radio-button, radio-group

Radio button list appear vertically rather than horizontally. Appears alright on Chrome and Firefox. We are using angular js 1.7.

[radio group from IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy8bc.png)

[radio group from Firefox 60.3.0 esr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j1yk.png)

[HTML code snippet for the radio group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AYtC.png)

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-if="feedbackChoices &amp;&amp; feedbackChoices.length > 1" id="629934096_not_helpful" class="choiceText f-b-choices-body ng-scope" ng-show="showChoices">
     <br>
        <div class="responsePrompt ng-scope" translate="">Where did we go wrong?</div>
        <br>
        <ul class="selectionRadio f-b-choices selectionGroup629934096_feedback_choices">
            <!-- ngRepeat: choice in feedbackChoices --><li ng-repeat="choice in feedbackChoices" class="ng-scope">
                <div>
                    <label><input id="948060864" class="f-b-input" name="selectionGroup" ng-click="submitFeedbackChoice(choice)" type="radio">                          
                        <label for="948060864" class="f-b-choices-label ng-scope ng-binding" translate="">The instructions did not apply</label>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: choice in feedbackChoices --><li ng-repeat="choice in feedbackChoices" class="ng-scope">
                <div>
                    <label><input id="948060864_2" class="f-b-input" name="selectionGroup" ng-click="submitFeedbackChoice(choice)" type="radio">                            
                        <label for="948060864_2" class="f-b-choices-label ng-scope ng-binding" translate="">The instructions were too long/hard to follow</label>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: choice in feedbackChoices --><li ng-repeat="choice in feedbackChoices" class="ng-scope">
                <div>
                    <label><input id="948060864_3" class="f-b-input" name="selectionGroup" ng-click="submitFeedbackChoice(choice)" type="radio">                            
                        <label for="948060864_3" class="f-b-choices-label ng-scope ng-binding" translate="">I need you to do this for me</label>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: choice in feedbackChoices -->       
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: My guess is that the "ul" element within doesn't inherit the style from its parent div. But why could it be so?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue, according to your code. But on my side, radio list appears vertical both on IE and Chrome. I think that maybe the styles have affected the result. Have you used some custom style? If it is, please share the style code so that it will be easier to help with you. Or you could use F12 developer tools to contrast the display of the style.

Comment: Thank you. Only style that's been used is width on the second div, which is set to 80%.